# Is there a way to call a class method inside an eval?

Tags: groovy, eval

I'm writing Groovy scripts that are pasted into a web-based system to be run. There is a 
class available to scripts run in this environment which I'll call `BrokenClass`. It has a
bug where it will only accept a string literal as its first parameter, but not a variable
with a string in it. So, this will work (it returns a list):

```
BrokenClass.reflist('something', 'name')
```

However, if I try to use a variable as the first parameter I get an error:

```
list_name = 'something'
BrokenClass.reflist(list_name, 'name')
```

This produces the message `Metadata RefList[something] cannot be accessed`.

I don't have any control over BrokenClass (aside from filing a bug on it). I tried to work
around the problem with something like this:

```
list_name = "foo"
list_call = "BrokenClass.reflist(${list_name}, 'name')"
list_values = Eval.me(list_call)
```

However, that produces an error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BrokenClass for class: Script1
```

I tried adding an `import` to my string, but then I get `unable to resolve class BrokenClass`.

Is there a way to use `BrokenClass` inside the eval'd string? Or some other way I haven't
considered to work around the bug in `BrokenClass.reflist`? A really long `switch` block
is out, because the possible list names change.

The method signature for `BrokenClass.reflist` is:

```
public static List<Object> reflist(String reflistName, String field);
```

Comment: Are you able to see the source code for BrokenClass?

Comment: No, I'm not. The class, and the whole web-based system, or controlled by a different group.

Comment: What's the method signature for BrokenClass.reflist()?

Comment: I updated the question to include it.

Comment: Have you tried declaring "list_name" as a "String" type?

Comment: No, just as you see it, since (theoretically) Groovy doesn't make you do that. It's worth a try, though.

Comment: I tried `String list_name = "foo"`, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I don't believe you've said what error you get.  You said "I get an error", but no other info. The other error message below refers to the other thing you tried to do.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the question.

Comment: Is it possible you used `something` instead of `Something` as String value for list_name in your second code line?

Comment: Try putting logging interceptor on list_name to see what string method calls reflist is making. http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-intercept-methods-with.html

Comment: @blackdrag No, that was a typo when I was sanitizing the code to post here.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Wow, that's scary looking. I'll spend some time staring at it and see if it starts to make sense.

Comment: Now I'm curious to see it! I forgot that the Interceptor is class rather than instance based, so it should also work with `BrokenClass.reflist('something', 'name')`.

Comment: I couldn't get the Interceptor thing to work. I suppose I could ask a new question about it so I could answer your question about this question, but at that point I think it's better to just say "there's not a workaround" and wait for people responsible for the broken class to fix it.  :-/

Comment: You said "A really long switch block is out, because the possible list names change." Where are the list names coming from? In the example you used a literal assigned to a variable. Is that real non working code or is the variable bring created another way (read from a file, database, etc)? Also, is BrokenClass written in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion that `BrokenClass.reflist()` is directly or indirectly doing an improper String comparison by using the == operator rather than `String.equals()`. See [this](http://codeinventions.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/string-comparison-in-java-double-equals-vs-equals.html) article for an explanation of the difference.

## The problem

Here's a demonstration of the problem:

```
def a = 'whatever'
def b = 'what' + 'ever'

assert doSomething('whatever') == 'OK'
assert doSomething(a) == 'OK'
assert doSomething(b) == 'ERROR'

def doSomething(String value) {
    if(value.is('whatever')) { // In Java this would be: value == "whatever"
        'OK'
    } else {
        'ERROR'
    }
}
```

Because it's using reference equality, which in Groovy is done by the `Object.is(Object)` method, `BrokenClass.reflist()` was inadvertently coded to work only with String literals: all String literals with the same value refer to the same String instance, resulting in an evaluation of True. A String composed at run time with the same value of a literal does not refer to the same String instance.

## Work around

Obviously `BrokenClass.reflist()` should be fixed. But you can work around the problem by using an *interned* String.

```
def b = 'what' + 'ever'

assert doSomething(b.intern()) == 'OK'

def doSomething(String value) {
    if(value.is('whatever')) { 
        'OK'
    } else {
        'ERROR'
    }
}
```

If the variable's value matches that of a String literal, then `variable.intern()` will return the same String instance as the matching literal. This would allow the Java == operator to work as you need it to.